# android studio api v2 map get a blank screen

Tags: android, android-maps

I try to build a simple google map app,and i just get the blank screen...
I did everything written here and it doesnt work please help

i just open android stuido click on maps activity then i changed my key 
i did build and copy the app-realse.apk to my mobile install and i get a blank screen i dunno why please help thx.

Maps activity

```
package com.example.zion.maptest;
import...
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
}


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
        // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}
private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
}}
```

android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it your issue add these two permission in your manifest

```
   <permission
              android:name="place your app package name here.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
              android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="place your app package name here.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
```